# Python Win32 Turn off Excel Calculation

Tags: python, excel, winapi, com

I get an excel version using the following python code;

```
import win32com.client as win32
xl = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Applcation')
```

I then want to turn off calculations, I thought this code would be the following but it's not?

```
xl.Calculation = '-4135' #-4135 is the enum value for xlManual
```

In addition does anyone know what else I could turn off to make loading an excel workbook faster?

Comment: `xl = win32.DispatchEx('Excel.Applcation')` - is this real code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a workbook first.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to refer to Application "class" first.

```py
xl.Application.Calculation = -4135 # to set xlCalculationManual
xl.Application.Calculation = -4105 # to set xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Use the [xlCalculation enumeration values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcalculation) as `int`'s.